# Parsing complicated XML that has recursive nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have a *really* complicated XML issue that I've spent days experimenting with code and searching the internet for a solution to with no joy.

There is a service that I'm calling which returns vehicle data in a really complicated and confusing XML format.  In several places, there are an unknown number of same-named-elements within the same named elements.  I need some attribute information from the lowest level, and also some information from outside the nested elements as well.

I need help with the following: (1) There can be zero, one, or over a dozen 'category' nodes on the way down to the price information. (2) There can be *multiple* 'price' elements... the first almost always has zero values, then there are additional 'ambiguousoption' elements, each with their own 'price' elements below it. (3) I need the list of 'category @id' values that go into the path to get down to the price level (if there are any).  (4) I need the stack of 'category @id' values to be sensitive to the 'ambiguousoption'... any 'category @id' values in the first 'ambiguousoption' list, then any that are in the second list.

What is happening in my code below is that it is grabbing the first (and only the first) 'price' information within each 'factoryoption' node, without regard to the fact that there can be multiple 'price' nodes in the 'factoryoption' node, one *outside* of the 'ambiguousoption' element, then an additional 'price' node inside *each* 'ambiguousoption' element.

What a nightmare.  It's got me totally confused.  Help!

Thanks,
Patrick

```
declare @xml xml = '<vehicledescription bestmodelname="Sierra 1500" beststylename="4WD Crew Cab 143.5&quot; SLE" besttrimname="SLE" bestmakename="GMC" country="US" language="en" modelyear="2014"><factoryoption optionkindid="5" utf="M" fleetonly="false" standard="false" chromecode="FE9" oemcode="FE9"><header id="1156">EMISSIONS</header><description>EMISSIONS, FEDERAL REQUIREMENTS</description><price unknown="false" invoicemin="0" invoicemax="0" msrpmin="0" msrpmax="0"><styleid>358200</styleid><installed cause="OptionCodeBuild" /></price></factoryoption><factoryoption optionkindid="6" utf="E" fleetonly="false" standard="false" chromecode="L83" oemcode="L83"><header id="1160">ENGINE</header><description>ENGINE, 5.3L ECOTEC3 V8 WITH ACTIVE FUEL MANAGEMENT</description><category id="1052"><category id="1213"><price unknown="false" invoicemin="963.6" invoicemax="963.6" msrpmin="1095" msrpmax="1095"><styleid>358200</styleid><installed cause="Engine" /></price></category></category></factoryoption><factoryoption optionkindid="7" utf="T" fleetonly="false" standard="true" chromecode="MYC" oemcode="MYC"><header id="1379">TRANSMISSION</header><description>TRANSMISSION, 6-SPEED AUTOMATIC, ELECTRONICALLY CONTROLLED</description><category id="1104"><category id="1130"><category id="1131" removed="true"><price unknown="false" invoicemin="0" invoicemax="0" msrpmin="0" msrpmax="0"><styleid>358200</styleid><installed cause="OptionCodeBuild" /></price></category></category></category></factoryoption><factoryoption optionkindid="28" utf="F" standard="false" oemcode="H1Y"><header id="1347">SEAT TRIM</header><description>JET BLACK, LEATHER-APPOINTED FRONT SEAT TRIM</description><category id="1077" removed="true"><category id="1078"><category id="1079" removed="true"><category id="1309" removed="true"><price unknown="false" invoicemin="0" invoicemax="0" msrpmin="0" msrpmax="0"><styleid>358200</styleid><installed cause="OptionCodeBuild"><ambiguousoption optionkindid="28" utf="F" fleetonly="false" standard="false" chromecode="H1Y-R" oemcode="H1Y"><header id="1347">SEAT TRIM</header><description>JET BLACK, LEATHER-APPOINTED FRONT SEAT TRIM</description><category id="1074"><category id="1077" removed="true"><category id="1078"><category id="1079" removed="true"><category id="1309" removed="true"><price unknown="false" invoicemin="0" invoicemax="0" msrpmin="0" msrpmax="0"><styleid>358200</styleid></price></category></category></category></category></category></ambiguousoption><ambiguousoption optionkindid="28" utf="F" fleetonly="true" standard="false" chromecode="H1Y-F" oemcode="H1Y"><header id="1347">SEAT TRIM</header><description>JET BLACK, LEATHER-APPOINTED FRONT SEAT TRIM</description><category id="1077" removed="true"><category id="1078"><category id="1079" removed="true"><category id="1156"><category id="1309" removed="true"><price unknown="false" invoicemin="0" invoicemax="0" msrpmin="0" msrpmax="0"><styleid>358200</styleid></price></category></category></category></category></category></ambiguousoption></installed></price></category></category></category></category></factoryoption><factoryoption optionkindid="33" utf="A" fleetonly="false" standard="true" chromecode="IO5" oemcode="IO5"><header id="1301">RADIO</header><description>AUDIO SYSTEM, 8" DIAGONAL COLOR TOUCH SCREEN WITH INTELLILINK, AM/FM/SIRIUSXM/HD</description><category id="1014"><category id="1017" removed="true"><category id="1149"><category id="1150"><category id="1211"><category id="1230"><category id="1299"><price unknown="false" invoicemin="0" invoicemax="0" msrpmin="0" msrpmax="0"><styleid>358200</styleid><installed cause="OptionCodeBuild" /></price></category></category></category></category></category></category></category></factoryoption><factoryoption utf="0" standard="false" oemcode="PDU"><header id="10750">ADDITIONAL EQUIPMENT</header><description>SLE VALUE PACKAGE</description><category id="1009"><category id="1010"><category id="1011"><category id="1034"><category id="1074"><category id="1151"><category id="1204"><category id="1221"><price unknown="false" invoicemin="1425.6" invoicemax="1425.6" msrpmin="1620" msrpmax="1620"><styleid>358200</styleid><installed cause="OptionCodeBuild"><ambiguousoption utf="0" fleetonly="false" standard="false" chromecode="PDU-R" oemcode="PDU"><header id="10750">ADDITIONAL EQUIPMENT</header><description>SLE VALUE PACKAGE</description><category id="1009"><category id="1010"><category id="1011"><category id="1034"><category id="1074"><category id="1151"><category id="1204"><category id="1221"><price unknown="false" invoicemin="1425.6" invoicemax="1425.6" msrpmin="1620" msrpmax="1620"><styleid>358200</styleid></price></category></category></category></category></category></category></category></category></ambiguousoption><ambiguousoption utf="0" fleetonly="true" standard="false" chromecode="PDU-F" oemcode="PDU"><header id="10750">ADDITIONAL EQUIPMENT</header><description>SLE VALUE PACKAGE</description><category id="1009"><category id="1010"><category id="1011"><category id="1034"><category id="1074"><category id="1151"><category id="1204"><category id="1221"><price unknown="false" invoicemin="1425.6" invoicemax="1425.6" msrpmin="1620" msrpmax="1620"><styleid>358200</styleid></price></category></category></category></category></category></category></category></category></ambiguousoption></installed></price></category></category></category></category></category></category></category></category></factoryoption></vehicledescription>'
select @xml

SELECT
--  Nodes.node.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS category,
  Nodes.node.value('(header/@id)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS headerid,
  Nodes.node.value('(header/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS headertext,
  Nodes.node.value('description[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS description,
  Nodes.node.value('(.//price/@invoicemin)[1]', 'money') AS invoicemin,
  Nodes.node.value('(.//price/@invoicemax)[1]', 'money') AS invoicemax,
  Nodes.node.value('(.//price/@msrpmin)[1]', 'money') AS msrpmin,
  Nodes.node.value('(.//price/@msrpmax)[1]', 'money') AS msrpmax,
  Nodes.node.value('(.//price/styleid/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS styleid,
  Nodes.node.value('(.//price/installed/@cause)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS installcause
FROM
  @xml.nodes('//factoryoption') AS Nodes(node);
```

Comment: Post your source data and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Take it step-by-step

```
FROM
  @xml.nodes('//factoryoption') AS Nodes(node);
```

This will only yield one row for every `<factoryoption>` element, regardless of depth.  You need to fan that out.

```
FROM
  @xml.nodes('//factoryoption') AS Nodes1(factoryoption)
CROSS APPLY
  @xml.nodes('category') AS Nodes2(category)
```

This will yield one row for every `<category>` element that is a child of a `<factoryoption>`

```
FROM
  @xml.nodes('//factoryoption') AS Nodes1(factoryoption)
CROSS APPLY
  factoryoption.nodes('category') AS Nodes2(category)
CROSS APPLY
  category.nodes('price') AS Nodes3(price)
```

This will yield one row for every `<price>` element that is a child of a `<category>` element that is a child of a `<factoryoption>`

You need to first fan out your xml.  When you don't do that and instead use something like `(.//price/@invoicemin)[1]`, you are asking "indiscriminately search the whole subtree for a `<price>` element with a `@invoicemin` attribute and return the `[1]` (i.e. first) one you find.

Comment: Thanks - that gets me part of the way there.  How can I then add in logic to capture 'ambiguousoption' data?  The tree is made up of zero/one/more 'category' nodes, followed by zero/one/more 'ambiguousoption' nodes, followed by zero/one/more additional 'category' nodes, followed by a 'price'.